# Are there any real world rostest examples using parameters?

Tags: rostest, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The last snippet at http://wiki.ros.org/rostest/Writing defines a parameter. However, I could not find any code I could test that show cases that this actually works.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227493/are-there-any-real-world-rostest-examples-using-parameters?/) by [chaoflow](https://answers.ros.org/users/26052/chaoflow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rostest` basically uses `roslaunch` files (http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML). And in launch files you can specify parameters (http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) as mentioned in your referenced wiki page.

I think you can safely assume that parameters from launch files get correctly set on the parameter server when you start them. Actually there are specifically tests which ensure such fundamental functionality doesn't regress (rostest launch file: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/test/test_roslaunch/test/params_basic.test and the corresponding unit test: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/test/test_roslaunch/test/params_basic.py) and they currently pass.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chaoflow](https://answers.ros.org/users/26052/chaoflow/) on 2016-02-26**:
Thanks for your quick answer! I meanwhile identified `launch-prefix` to be the culprit: Nodes with a `launch-prefix` will attempt to connect to the default ros master (which might be running and lacking the parameters) instead of connecting to the custom ros master started by rostest,